# Building a cross platform mobile app for a website

Tags: android, ios, cordova

I have a website setup using html/css/javascript with php/mysql as backend.
I would like to build an app for my website for iOS and Android but I'm not sure where to start.
The app needs to do user authentication, get data from the database, send push notifications etc.

I have some iOS experience but no Android so I was thinking Phonegap would be one way to go but I'm not sure yet. I don't have an API setup for the website but I figured if I will be using phonegap I won't need one?

Could any one guide me to the correct direction?

Comment: For starters such as yourself, i recommend doing you mobile app using Jquery Mobile, and build a Webkit browser using android sdk and xcode which takes 10 minutes. That way you can build your app very quickly and easy and when you finally move to native at least you know how you want your app to look like and function. The performance of Jquery mobile on mobiles and tablets is great as long as you dont bloat the application. if you are keen to learn Java and objective C/Swift by all means go native.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All depends the App you have to do, phonegap is not magic you have to design a new "website" responsive ( Iphone / Ipad / Android have differents screen size ).

Each time you will need data from server you will have to use Ajax, so you have to think about structure before you start your project.

1  : define all special functions you needs ( GPS / Camera / etc )

2  : check if you can have these functions via phonegap/cordova for the platform you want ( Android / iOS )

3  : Create the layout of your app
         Choose the right tools Bootsrap/jquery/ jquery mobile / angularjs / handlebars etc

4  : test html/css version of your app inside phonegap
     if everything looks good you can begin to think about ajax / php coding

Hope it could help you ,-)